# Como hacer que me retorne la variable con los valores asignados dentro de un TRY

Tags: java, android, android-volley

```
public Usuario buscar(final Usuario nombreUsuario) {

    Log.i("Usuario:", nombreUsuario.toString());
    final Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    final String url = EstructuraURL.URL_LOGIN;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                usuario.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                usuario.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                usuario.setNombre(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));

                Log.i("Respuesta", response);

                if (success.equals("1")) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, usuario.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Error!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.i("Respueta", error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("nombreUsuario", nombreUsuario.getEmail());
            params.put("password", nombreUsuario.getPassword());

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    return null;
}
```

Aquí el código, si al final pongo return usuario; los valores que me dan son todos nulos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que las llamadas son asíncronas, siguiendo un patrón similar a una llamada AJAX, por lo que no se puede *devolver* nada:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //... código que se ejecuta cuando tenemos la respuesta
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //... código que se ejecuta en caso de error
            }
        }
) {
    //... código extendiendo la clase StringRequest
};
```

Todo este código *construye* la llamada y asigna un valor a stringRequest, pero no espera la respuesta antes de pasar a la siguiente línea de código.

La respuesta llegará en algún momento y provocará la ejecución del método `onResponse`. En lugar de devolver el valor, puedes crear un método en tu clase que reciba como parámetro una instancia de Usuario y llamar a este método desde el método onResponse:

```
public void buscar(final Usuario nombreUsuario, MiClaseConMetodo mccm) {

    Log.i("Usuario:", nombreUsuario.toString());
    final Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    final String url = EstructuraURL.URL_LOGIN;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,

        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //... código que se ejecuta cuando tenemos la respuesta
                mccm.tengoUsuario(usuario);
            }
        },
        ...
```